# Can I define a subroutine that can be called like a built-in, everywhere?

Tags: perl, subroutine, global

Currently, during debugging, I tend to insert

```
carp Dumper \@foo, \%bar;
```

statements into my code, and regularly run into the problem that `Carp` and `Data::Dumper` are not imported in the current package. To avoid this problem, I defined the following sub in a central file that's always included:

```
sub main::bla {
    use Carp; use Data::Dumper;
    carp Dumper @_;
}
```

So now I can do

```
main::bla \@foo, \%bar;
```

everywhere, but the `main::` annoys me. Is there something like a global package that's always imported, in any package, automatically (just like built-ins practically are imported everywhere)?

Comment: I'd like to note that `use` is a compile-time directive; in other words, if you use `use` in some module that is always included these modules would be always included as well. And putting a `use` inside some code that might not be called (i.e., in the false branch of a conditional, for example) doesn't prevent it from being processed.

Comment: @raina77ow: Nice idea. I tried to hijack the `import` method of the commonly-included module to install `bla` in the calling package. But the common module does not have `import` by default, so once any other module has `require`d or `use`d it, other modules do not need to `use` it again since they have to call the common module's methods explicitly anyway (i.e. `Common::foo()` instead of `foo()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just call it

```
::bla( \@foo, \%bar );
```

In earlier days, I used to put util functions in a `Ut` package. And that was fine, but I noticed that my code wasn't really as modular as I thought of it. Each module that depended on `Ut` functions being there could only succeed if somebody took the trouble to *build* that namespace.

In the end, I considered `use` and `require` statements as simply documenting dependencies. There are more flexible ways to change what code is called by library modules, rather than changing their implementation in main.

For example, you could do this in a single `use` statement.

```
use Ut blah => sub { 
    use Carp; 
    use Data::Dumper;
    carp Dumper @_;
};
```

And define the import:

```
sub import { 
    shift; # It's just me
    my ( $name, $impl ) = @_;
    if ( $name eq 'blah' && ref( $impl ) eq 'CODE' ) { 
        *blah = $_[1];
    }
    ...
}
```

I still use the `ut` pattern, when I'm developing a lot of code at once. But I don't mind writing

```
ut:dump_var( $var )
```

as opposed to saving 3-4 characters (because sometimes I call it `U::`).

Now, it appears that you don't want to do this long term, and dumping out your variables is a useful thing for development. If you really want to do this, [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments) does it like so:

```
### @foo
### %bar
```

All it takes is one use statement.

```
use Smart::Comments;
```

Comment: Remember that `'` is an archaic form of `::`, and you can say `sub U'dump_var { ... } ... U'dump_var($var)` is it doesn't fubar your syntax highlighter.

Comment: @mob, I've never used `'` and I shudder to think of doing so. I've always wondered what suggested it. If I really wanted to save typing, i'd just call it `dv`: `U::dv`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just better to make another Package with Export and needed things?
Like, MyTest.pm:

```
package MyTest;

use strict;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;


use base qw( Exporter );
our @EXPORT = qw(
    debug
)

sub debug {
    carp Dumper @_;
}

1;
```

So you can then just write in your script:

```
use MyTest;

debug {a => 'b', c => 'd' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: [Some symbols](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#The_Syntax_of_Variable_Names) are magic in that they always refer to their values in the `main` package. You can assign subroutines to these symbols that and they will be visible in any package.

```
{
    package Foo;

    # special names _ ARGV ARGVOUT ENV INC SIG STDERR STDIN STDOUT
    sub ENV { print "In main::ENV ...\n" }
    sub STDIN { print "In main::STDIN ...\n" }
    sub _ { print "In main::_\n" }

    # names that begin with ^ + upper case letter, or all digits
    *{^T} = sub { scalar localtime };
    *{^Gmtime} = sub { scalar gmtime };
    *43 = sub { 42 };

    use Data::Dumper;
    *{^D} = \&Data::Dumper::Dumper;
}

{
    package Bar;
    &ENV;


    STDIN();
    print "The time is ", &^T, "\n";
    print "In London it is ", &{^Gmtime}, "\n";
    print "The answer is ", &43, "\n";

    print "\@foo is ", &^D( \@foo );
}
```

None of this is recommended, unless you want to drive the next person who maintains your code insane.